# Can I have multiple parameter values in ansible module?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have multiple parameters values in ansible e.g., `state=present`, `mounted`?

---

```
  - name: create partition
    parted: device=/dev/sdc number=1 state=present
  - name: Create a ext4 filesystem on /dev/sdc1 and check disk blocks
    filesystem: fstype=ext4 dev=/dev/sdc1
  - name: mount the directory
    mount: path=/data src=/dev/sdc1 fstype=ext4 state=present
```

Comment: Ever read this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but the parameter must support it. For example the `yum` module accept list of names of packages. But only on single value of `state`. So what you should do is to read the documentation of the module parameters and check if it support multiple values (list).